# List returned by SafeConfigParser is [''], but shows a len() of 1

Tags: python, list, configparser

I have a config file something like:

```
[Expected Response]
    GlobalResponse:

    UniqueResponse:
        1221
```

What I'm trying to do is, if `GlobalResponse` is empty, then we rely on `UniqueResponse` being set.

```
subConfigParser = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)   
subConfigParser.read(os.path.join(relativeRunPath, 'veri.cfg'))
commands = subConfigParser.get('Command List', 'commands').strip().split("\n")
expectedResponse = subConfigParser.get('Expected Response', 'GlobalResponse').strip().split("\n")
print expectedResponse
print len(expectedResponse)
if not expectedResponse:
    expectedResponse = subConfigParser.get('Expected Response', 'UniqueResponse').strip().split("\n")
    print "Size of unique: {}".format(len(expectedResponse))
    if len(expectedResponse) != len(commands):
        sys.exit(1)
```

However, this is the output I get:

```
['']   # print expectedResponse
1      # print len(expectedResponse)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What are you expecting? `['']` is a list with one item, so naturally its length is 1.

Comment: Are you confused why you are getting `['']` back? Or why `len([''])` is equal to `1`? The latter is expected behavior.

Comment: to further kindall's comment `[]` is a list with len 0

Comment: Hmm ok, I wasn't aware that `['']` == len of 1. Sorry, I'm pretty new to Python in general. So I guess it's an issue with ConfigParser returning something when I expected it to just return nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected.

`['']` is a list object that contains `''`, which is an empty string object.  Even though `''` is empty, it is still an object and therefore counts as an element inside the list.  Thus, `len` returns `1` because the list has one item.

Below is a demonstration to explain better:

```
>>> len([]) # Length of an empty list
0
>>> # Length of a list that contains 1 string object which happens to be empty.
>>> len([''])
1
>>> # Length of a list that contains 2 string objects which happen to be empty.
>>> len(['', ''])
2
>>>
```

---

Perhaps you meant to write:

```
if not expectedResponse or not expectedResponse[0]:
```

The condition of this if-statment will pass if `expectedResponse` is empty `[]` or if its first element is empty `['']`.

Note that if `expectedResponse` always contains an element, you should write:

```
if not expectedResponse[0]:
```

This will test if the first (only) element of `expectedResponse` is empty.